# How to have nested brackets with a common element

Tags: brackets, nesting

I'm trying to do something like in the image. However LaTeX does not seems to support this kind of nested brackets.
Now I have

```
\begin{align*}

\overbrace{
    \underbrace{
        \overbrace{
            [1,2,3...], [1/2,3/2...]
        }^\text{Rationals}
        \overbrace{
            [\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3} ...], 
    }_\text{Algebraic}
        \underbrace{
            [\pi...]
        }_\text{Transcendentals}
        }^\text{Irrationals}
}^\text{Real}

\end{align*}
```

[image: Brackets with common element]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might consider using `tikzmark`. Basically, the idea is to place markers around the mathematics and to then use these markers to places the braces and labels in an overlaid `tikzpicture environment`.

You will need to allow sufficient space for this in your document i.e. some extra space above and below the diagram so that when the braces and labels are overlaid on the page, they occupy space rather than colliding with content. Alternatively, you could create the diagram separately and then include it as a graphic image.

[image: reals]

Code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,decorations.pathreplacing}
\begin{document}
\tikzmark{a}
\[
  \tikzmark{c}[1,2,3,\dots]\tikzmark{d}\;\tikzmark{e}[1/2,3/2,\dots]\tikzmark{f}\;\tikzmark{g}[\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3},\dots]\tikzmark{h}\;\tikzmark{m}[\pi,\dots]\tikzmark{n}
\]
\tikzmark{b}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay, decoration={brace, amplitude=5pt}]
  \foreach \i / \j in {a/0, b/10pt, c/0, d/0, e/0, f/0, g/0, h/0, m/0, n/0} \coordinate (\i) at ([yshift=\j]{pic cs:\i});
  \draw [decorate] (c |- a) -- (a -| f) node (r) [midway, above, yshift=5pt] {Rationals};
  \draw [decorate] (g |- a) -- (a -| n) node [midway, above, yshift=5pt] {Irrationals};
  \draw [decorate] (b -| h) -- (c |- b)  node [midway, below, yshift=-5pt] {Algebraics};
  \draw [decorate] (b -| n) -- (m |- b) node [midway, below, yshift=-5pt] {Transcendentals};
  \draw [decorate] (c |- r.north) -- (r.north -| n) node [midway, above, yshift=5pt] {Reals};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

One possibility to achieve this is by using the [`underoverlap`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/underoverlap/underoverlap.pdf) package. To understand the following code, please also have a look at [its documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/underoverlap/underoverlap.pdf).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{underoverlap}

\begin{document}
\[
    \overbrace{
        \UOLunderbrace{
             \overbrace{
                 \boxed{1,2,3,\dots \text{ Integers}\vphantom{\sqrt{2}}} 
                 \quad
                 \boxed{1/2,3/2,\dots\vphantom{\sqrt{2}}}
             }^{\text{Rational Numbers}}
             \quad
        }[
             \boxed{\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3},\dots}
        ]_{\text{Algebraic Numbers}}
        \UOLoverbrace{
            \quad
            \underbrace{\boxed{\pi,e,\dots\vphantom{\sqrt{2}}}}_text{\makebox[0pt]{Transcendental Numbers}}
        }^{\text{Irrationals}}
    }^{\text{Real Numbers}}
\]
\end{document}
```

*To get the idea of this, you can ignore the following cosmetical commands when reading for the first time:*

- `\vphantom{}` *helps to make all boxes of the same height.*
- `\makebox[0pt]{}` *takes care of the fact that the label »Transcendental Numbers« is wider than its brace.*
  [image]

Comment: Unfortunately I do not know how to align all the far left and far right tips of the braces exactly vertically. At the moment they are almost but not exactly above each other. Maybe someone else can help with this. Would be interested too.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a `pstricks` solution, as faithful as possible to the O.P.'s post. It relies on the `\psDefBoxNodes` command, from `pst-node`, which allows to consider the box defined by a text as having $10$ nodes on its contour, and $2$ inside it (at the centre of the box and at the centre of the base line), thus allowing for very precise connections. Also, I used as sans-serif font , Cabin Condensed:

```
\documentclass[x11names]{article}%

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[TS1,T1]{fontenc }
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage{cabin}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}
\usepackage{pst-node}%

\newlength\myboxwd
\settowidth\myboxwd{\textsf{1/3, 7/2, etc.}}
\newcommand\mystrut{\vphantom{\sf g$\mathsf{\sqrt 3}$}}

\newcommand\myBoxNodes[2]{\psDefBoxNodes{#1}{\fcolorbox{IndianRed4! 75!}{white}{\mystrut\makebox[\myboxwd]{#2}}}}

\begin{document}

\fontfamily{CabinCondensed-TLF}\selectfont
\setlength\fboxrule{1pt}

\begin{postscript}
    \myBoxNodes{INT}{Integers} \enspace\myBoxNodes{FR}{1/3, 7/2, etc.}\enspace \myBoxNodes{ALG}{$\mathsf{\sqrt \text{2}, \sqrt \text{3}}$, etc.} \enspace \myBoxNodes{TR}{$\mathsf{\pi}$, e, etc.}
    \psset{shortput = nab, nodesep=3pt, angle=90, arm=6pt, linearc=0.1, linewidth=0.6pt, linecolor=IndianRed3! 60!}
    \pcbar[nodesep=16pt, arm=10pt, linearc=0.15](INT:tl)(TR:tr)^{Real Numbers}
    \pcbar(INT:tl)(FR:tr)^{Rationals} \pcbar(ALG:tl)(TR:tr)^{Irrationals}
    \psset{angle=-90}
    \pcbar(ALG:br)(INT:bl)^{Algebraic Numbers} \pcbar(TR:br)(TR:bl)^{\makebox[0pt]{Transcendentals}}
\end{postscript}

\end{document}
```

[image]